# OpenCV Conversion from cv::Mat -> std::string -> cv::Mat results in unexpected side effects

Tags: string, image, opencv, c++11, matrix

I am trying to convert an input image to string and then back to image like a complete cycle. I get `Clang-Tidy: Use of a signed integer operand with a binary bitwise operator` warning with an unexpected side effect (explained in screenshots below) when I try to specify `CV_8UC3` or `CV_8UC1` based on my knowledge about the input image. I am not sure what this means?

I am already aware of a [similar such question in a different context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50399090/10019073). But I am not sure how is my case related to that question.

This is my code :

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    bool color = argv[1];
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("../images/input.jpg", color);
    std::string img_str(img.begin<unsigned char>(), img.end<unsigned char>());
    auto* buffer = (unsigned char *) img_str.c_str();
    // Complaint happens at this line below
    cv::Mat dummy = cv::Mat(img.rows, img.cols, color ? CV_8UC3 : CV_8UC1, buffer);
    cv::imwrite("../images/output.jpg", dummy);
    return 0;
}
```

**Input image:**

[image]

**When `color == CV_8UC3`:**

[image]

**When `color == CV_8UC1`**

[image]

**Expected behavior**

Color image (replica of input image), when `color == CV_8UC3`

Grayscale image of input image, when `color == CV_8UC1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Use of a signed integer operand with a binary bitwise operator" - when using unsigned short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50399090/use-of-a-signed-integer-operand-with-a-binary-bitwise-operator-when-using-un)

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I am aware of that question. Scanned through it and tried to relate both situations. But I am not able to connect the relationship between that question and my problem. Hence this question is yet not resolved.

Comment: It is not an error. But it is a warning given by Clion. My code is fairly large (this segment is a tiny portion of it). I am curious whether this warning creates any dangerous side effects in a computer vision code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue myself by converting the image <-> string <-> image in an alternative way like below :

```
std::string ImageToString(const cv::Mat &img) {
    cv::Mat1b linear_img(img.reshape(1));
    return std::string(linear_img.begin(), linear_img.end());
}
```

After this the converted string/ images are perfect.